# How to clear a input field in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, field

How do I clear the input fields "add__description" & "add__value" after clicking the submit button in my Budget App. [In jQuery]

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bottom">
  <div class="add">
    <div class="add__container">
      <select class="add__type">
        <option value="inc" selected>+</option>
        <option value="exp">-</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" class="add__description" placeholder="Add description">
      <input type="number" class="add__value" placeholder="Value">
      <button class="add__btn"><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-outline"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I call a clear field function to clear the fields. I tried something like this...

```
clearFields: function() {
        $(".add__description, .add__value").val("");
    },
```

Here is the codePen link - [CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/crazydeveloper/pen/YdzKZP)

Comment: Please update the snippet I made with where you execute the clearFields

Comment: are you creating any plugin?

Comment: Please check the codePen link

Answer (score 3):

In the clear function simply do this:

```
    $(".add__description,.add__value").val("");
```

You were taking the elements in a wrong way. The class name is sufficient.

---

**EDIT:** code pen review

I think what you want to achieve is the fields getting cleared after the entry is added to the Income/Expenses list.

To achieve this you have to move the line

```
UICtrl.clearFields();
```

into the `eventBtn()` method, like this:

```
function eventBtn() {
    var input = UICtrl.getInp();

    var newItem = budgetCtrl.addItem(input.type, input.des, input.val);

    UICtrl.addListItem(newItem, input.type);
    UICtrl.clearFields();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery syntax is correct from @pid

You'll also need to include the call to `clearFields` in your `addListItem` method

```
addListItem: function(obj, type) {
    ...
    this.clearFields();
},
```

https://codepen.io/pxfunc/pen/XoWrzo

Comment: Thank You very much MikeM :) I really appreciate your precious time for me. Could you please tell why to call clearField function in addListItem? I already called that in controller.

Comment: @CrazyDeveloper it looks like what you had may have just been an ordering issue, I see what you're talking about with the controller calling `clearFields` however it's outside the `eventBtn()` method.  On my pen `clearFields` is called on `line 145`, but the `eventBtn()` method ends on `line 143`,

Answer (score 0):

```
clearFields: function() {
  $element.click(function (e) {
    $('.add__description, .add__value').val('');
  }
},
```

```js
$(function(){
  $('button.add__btn').click(function(){
     $('.add__description, .add__value').val('');
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bottom">
  <div class="add">
    <div class="add__container">
      <select class="add__type">
        <option value="inc" selected>+</option>
        <option value="exp">-</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" class="add__description" placeholder="Add description">
      <input type="number" class="add__value" placeholder="Value">
      <button class="add__btn"><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-outline"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: How about an explanation to go along with your code?